# Create frameworks for iOS bundled with unity data and its library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, unity-game-engine

This is regarding creating the framework in iOS, as I have a bundle of unity which I want to create a framework, with data with-holding and linking library from Unity as libiPhone-lib.a. So without adding any library in the bundle target, the compilation works fine, if I include libiPhone-lib.a file, it generates a warning as:

warning: implicit declaration of function 'UnitySendMessage'

The UnitySendMessage is a function which is being called from the dedicated libiPhone-lib.a framework.

Any suggestions regarding this concern will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that, in the file where it occurred, UnitySendMessage was called without the compiler having seen a declaration for the function. You need to edit the file and #import the header that contains UnitySendMessage (or #include if it is a .c file)
.

Comment: Idz, I have been trying to locate this function declaration however it seams that Unity have bundled that within their set of library. So the linking is going like this... My main app -> Unity asset bundled framework -> Unity bundled their own sets of library. Any suggestions in this topology? Thanks.

Comment: This is a compile time error, not a link error. The full error message should tell you the file and line number where the error occurred. This is the file you need to edit. The documentation for the framework you are using should tell you which header file the `UnitySendMessage` function is in.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity folks seem to have neglected to include a header declaring this function. You can either declare it yourself, or just ignore the warning.